# Javascript RegEx - Split using text between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a script and need to split strings which contain both html tags and text. I'm trying to isolate the tags and eliminate the text.

For example, I want this:

```
string = "<b>Text <span>Some more text</span> more text</b>";
```

to be split like this:

```
separation = string.split(/some RegExp/);
```

and become:

```
separation[0] = "<b>";
separation[1] = "<span>";
separation[2] = "</span>";
separation[3] = "</b>";
```

I would really appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: What is supposed to happen in the case of something like `<b attribute="...">`. Do you want everything up to the `>`? If so, you'll need a more advanced parser to cover all bases... Or consider using the one build into your browser (HTML -> DOM).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want to look into `String.match` instead:

```
var str = "<b>Text <span>Some more text</span> more text</b>";
var separation = str.match(/<[^]+?>/g);

console.log(separation); // ["<b>", "<span>", "</span>", "</b>"]
```

Comment: Actually, do you have any idea what the regular expression would be to cover `<span class='class'>` as well.

Comment: @user433351: This one should work for that already. (Unless it's split across multiple lines?)